# Web Api 2 or Generic Handler to serve images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to create an image handler, but i am torn between using `Web API 2` or just a normal `Generic Handler (ashx)`

I have implemented both in the past, but which one is the most correct one.
I found an old SO post [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688074/do-i-use-a-web-service-or-a-httphandler-to-serve-images) but is it still really relevant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebApi is fully capable and I prefer it. The other answer is right that JSON and XML are default, but you can add your own MediaFormatter and serve any content type for any model. This allows you to perform content negotiation and provide different content based on the Accept header or file extension. Let's pretend our model is a "User". Imagine asking for a "User" as json, xml, jpg, pdf. With WebApi, we can use file extensions or the Accept header and ask for /Users/1 or Users/1.json for JSON, Users/1.jpg for jpg, Users/1.xml for xml, /Users/1.pdf for pdf, etc. All of these could also just be /Users/1 with different Accept headers with quality so your clients could ask for Users/1 with an Accept header asking for jpg first, but fall back to png.

Here is an example of how to create a formatter for .jpg.

```cs
public class JpegFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public JpegFormatter()
    {
        //this allows a route with extensions like /Users/1.jpg
        this.AddUriPathExtensionMapping(".jpg", "image/jpeg");

        //this allows a normal route like /Users/1 and an Accept header of image/jpeg
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        //Can this formatter read binary jpg data?
        //answer true or false here
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        //Can this formatter write jpg binary if for the given type?
        //Check the type and answer. You could use the same formatter for many different types.
        return type == typeof(User);
    }

    public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
        TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        //value will be whatever model was returned from your controller
        //you may need to check data here to know what jpg to get

        var user = value as User;
        if (null == user)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        var stream = SomeMethodToGetYourStream(user);

        await stream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
    }
}
```

Now we need to register our formatter (typically App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        //typical route configs to allow file extensions
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ext", "{controller}/{id}.{ext}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        //remove any default formatters such as xml
        config.Formatters.Clear();

        //order of formatters matter!
        //let's put JSON in as the default first
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        //now we add our custom formatter
        config.Formatters.Add(new JpegFormatter());
    }
}
```

And finally, our controller

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var user = SomeMethodToGetUsersById(id);

        return this.Ok(user);
    }
}
```

Your controller will not have to change as you add different formatters. It simply returns your model and then formatters kick in later in the pipeline. I love formatters as it provides such a rich api. You can read more about formatters on the [WebApi website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters).

Comment: please tell me what is the output of `<img src='/api/image/getImg' /> `when your default formatter is JSON? I think the answer based on your sample above is that it will not work

Comment: I answered this same question on your answer, but to answer here as well: The default formatter would run here and be json. This is an HTML issue with not being able to express an Accept header in an image tag. Because of this, you need to add a file extension `src='/api/image/getImg.jpg'`. This will then route to the JpegFormatter. Any client capable of setting headers can simply put the Accept header to image/jpeg and the formatter will be ran.

Comment: @ManOVision, thanks for your reply, this is exactly how i did it in the past. And i think in the scenario that i want to use it your solution is probably best.

Answer (score 6):

The correct one is **ashx** the reason is the **content type**. If you use Web Api the content type a.k.a media formatter(format) of your response is the one defined for all your services meaning JSON, XML or oData.

```
//Global Asax, Web Api register methods is used to defined WebApi formatters
```

**`config.Formatters.Insert(0, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());`**

However an image is a binary therefore you need to send the image in its original format and not as JSON or XML

**`response.AddHeader("content-type", "image/png");`**

```
 response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
 response.Flush();
```

That is why the **ashx** is the right tool for that job.

One additional advantage is that you have more control over your output without the need to code a new "formatter"(the way to make WebApi to resolve this issue) for each image type that you want to return by doing something like in Ashx file:

```
var png = Image.FromFile("some.png");
png.Save("a.gif", var png = Image.FromFile("some.png");
png.Save("a.gif", ImageFormat.Gif); //Note you can save the new image into a MemoryStream to return it later in the same method.
```

And you have wide variety of types to play with:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Important:** It is clear for all of us that both **WebApi** and **Ashx** can return images. I am not saying in any way that you can't achieve this with WebApi all I am saying is why I believe Ashx is the right choice.

Comment: WebAPI has no problem handling binary format whatsoever, all you need is to create a formatter.

Comment: And yet you will be affecting all routings under that formatter instead of one single method that returns an image. I didn't say you can't it just not the right tool

Comment: If you want to send binary format, you want to affect all routes which return it. I don't understand your point.

Comment: Check my answer, each formatter has to return if it can respond to the given type. It only gets applied to those types you explicitly say it can format.

Comment: @ManOVision please tell me what is the output of `<img src='/api/image/getImg' /> `when your default formatter is JSON?

Comment: Add the file extension. You are correct, the default formatter with no file extension will return JSON. Add a .jpg to it `src='/api/image/getImg.jpg'` and now a binary jpg will be returned. I have done this exact thing hundreds of times. Web clients are the only reason I need to add the file extension. All other clients simply change their Accept header and binary is served.

Comment: But your are altering and defining the content type of the image from the client it may be png or something else like bmp from my POV you shouldn't let the client decide your image content type from a dynamic generator

Comment: You build a formatter for each binary type your api supports. If it supports both jpg and png, that's fine. During upload, the client needs to tell the api what format the binary is, and during download the client needs to tell the api what format it "Accepts" via header or file ext. No binary is altered. If the api only has jpg and the client asks for png, the api should respond with a 415 Unsupported Media Type response.

Comment: Your latest code edit has nothing to do with an advantage of ashx vs web api. That is a benefit of .net being able to open and save various image types. You can code a single formatter to return any image format and convert it just as you did. As with most things, there are pros and cons to any approach. Only the OP will be able to determine the right process. This question is now looking like an opinion based question and should probably be closed. If the OP want's a RESTful API, WebApi is the right choice, otherwise a handler would work fine.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your comments. I realized in both cases there are pros and cons. In the end i am going to end up using the Web Api, as i already have an web Api.  If i didn't have the pre-existing Apii i would have gone for the ashx. (Added upvote)

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of flexibility and customization. I personally would go for httpHandler. So to answer your question, it really depends on your requirements.

First thing WebAPI is the result of evolution all the way from http (GET/POST) calls to web services and the need of being able to transfer data in less cost as opposed to web services. HttpHandlers utilized same concept long time before web apis. Basically web apis are nothing but a http page without its user interface (if you want to).

Few things need to know before choosing HttpHandler or Web Api

1. development time - whether you know both very well and what will take less time for you to implement
2. As ManOVision mentioned in his answer, the routing user/1 you can still implement with simple code and httphandler so you don't really need Web API for that. only you may have to right the code manually adding up a little time in development
3. Flexibility, I personally like this part since I will be able to control the response content type as I want depending upon the data user provides. I don't need to perform session checks and redirect to any page. I can still control this behavior to whatever I want. web API also you can do but mostly things are taken at run time by itself to the configuration we put in place at the development.
4. rendering web page is the same for both. Although httphandler being easy so why to use Web API?

There might more comparison (As a manager I think from management side as well and not completely technical perspective) so you may have to weigh your options and decide what to do. Since handler file is anyway foundation of web API, I would say it gives more power to developer than web api does. just like a http socket would do more than httphandler.